# Is there an equivalent of unix "comm" command in R?

Tags: unix, r, comm

I have one master file with a list of unique IDs and want to align three files with subsets of IDs alongside this, ending up with:
Column 1  (id1, id2, id3, id4 etc) Column 2 (space, id2, space, space) Column 3 (id1, id2, space space) Column 4 (id1, space id3 space) etc.
I have a unique list in R and the "comm" command in unix seems to do this - is there an equivalent in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of your data is not very clear, but if you start with the following vectors :

```
R> master <- paste("id",1:10,sep="")
R> sub1 <- paste("id",c(2,3,5),sep="")
R> sub2 <- paste("id",c(1,4,8,9),sep="")
R> master
[1] "id1"  "id2"  "id3"  "id4"  "id5"  "id6"  "id7"  "id8"  "id9"  "id10"
R> sub1
[1] "id2" "id3" "id5"
R> sub2
[1] "id1" "id4" "id8" "id9"
```

You can create a data frame from your *master* list of ids, and use these ids as row names :

```
R> df <- data.frame(master=master, row.names=master)
R> df
     master
id1     id1
id2     id2
id3     id3
id4     id4
id5     id5
id6     id6
id7     id7
id8     id8
id9     id9
id10   id10
```

Then you can add new columns for each subset the following way :

```
R> df[sub1, "sub1"] <- sub1
R> df[sub2, "sub2"] <- sub2
```

With the following result :

```
R> df
     master sub1 sub2
id1     id1 <NA>  id1
id2     id2  id2 <NA>
id3     id3  id3 <NA>
id4     id4 <NA>  id4
id5     id5  id5 <NA>
id6     id6 <NA> <NA>
id7     id7 <NA> <NA>
id8     id8 <NA>  id8
id9     id9 <NA>  id9
id10   id10 <NA> <NA>
```